# How to inherit a form from a class library (on a separate solution)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a custom form from Solution1

```
public partial class MasterForm : Form
{
    public MasterForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

however, upon creating a new solution (Solution2), trying to inherit the MasterForm (from Solution1).
I don't see the MasterForm in the Inheritance Picker (Unless I browse for the .dll).

**Update**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the project referenced? Do you have a `using` for its namespace?

Comment: using the namespace? does it mean, manually setting the inherited form through codes? I already referenced the Solution1 but still no MasterForm in Inheritance Picker

Comment: Oh, I understand now that you're referring to creating an "Inherited Form" using the Visual Studio wizard?

Comment: Yes, kindly check my update above

Comment: I've just tested this in Visual Studio 2017 and I can reproduce your issue. I recommend filing a bug report using the feedback tool in the top-right of the Visual Studio window. For the meantime you'll probably have to manually create the inherited form.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is, the two solutions are referenced, like if Soln 1 is using the class from Soln 2, Soln 2 has to be added as a reference to Soln 1.

Once it is done, the namespace of the class for Soln 2 has to be used (usually the Visual Studio IDE will give the suggestion for the reference issue if you are using it).
But this should solve the issue.

Comment: Yes but my concern is the Inheritance Picker (when adding an Inherited Form though wizard)

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your problem. It seems that I can do nothing for Inheritance Picker.

However, I suggest that you can write a small code to inherit the form.

Code:

```
   public partial class Form1 :Inheritance.MasterForm
```

You can change form to Inheritance.MasterForm to do it.

Finally, you can look at the form from the dll.